# How to add gutters to a flex row

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm new to tailwind and more familiar with frameworks such as Foundation and Bootstrap. My understanding of tailwind is that it is a utility based framework and structured in such a way that the developer shouldn't need to write any custom CSS for the vast majority of situations. I am a full stack developer with nearing 10 years' experience. It shouldn't be this hard for me to transition to a new framework.

My issue is giving the following markup, tailwind just doesn't work. I'm assuming that the issue here is my understanding of tailwind, but that would indicate a significant shortfall in their documentation.

```
<div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap space-x-4">
    <div class="w-full lg:w-7/12">
    </div>
    <div class="w-full lg:w-5/12">
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the right hand column wrapping to a new line. This should not be the default behavoiur, surely??

If I were to use Foundation, the following markup would suffice and more importantly would work:

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="large-7 cell">
    </div>
    <div class="large-5 cell">
    </div>
</div>
```

The resultant layout should be like this for large screens and should stack on mobile.

[image: Desired layout]

People of the internet: tell me where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This results in the right hand column wrapping to a new line. This should not be the default behavoiur, surely??

The `flex-wrap` class applies `flex-wrap: wrap` which allows elements to flow to a new line when there isn't enough space along the flex axis, in this case, the horizontal axis.

At the `lg` breakpoint, we have two `<div>` elements, with `width: 58.333333%` (from `lg:w-7/12`) and `width: 41.666667%` (from `lg:w-5/12`). We then also have `margin-left: 1rem` on the second `<div>` element from the parent `space-x-4`. This means that the overall horizontal space taken up by both `<div>` elements in total is `100% + 1rem` which is greater than the available horizontal space of `100%` and thus the elements wrap.

To have the elements not wrap, you could:

- Remove the margin

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

  <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
      <div class="w-full lg:w-7/12 bg-red-500 h-10">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-5/12 bg-blue-500 h-10">
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Incorporate the margin into a calculation into the element widths:

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

  <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap space-x-4">
      <div class="w-full lg:w-[calc(theme(width.7/12)-(theme(space.4)/2))] bg-red-500 h-10">
      </div>
      <div class="w-full lg:w-[calc(theme(width.5/12)-(theme(space.4)/2))] bg-blue-500 h-10">
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Apply `flex-grow` instead of `width` to to let the layout engine distribute the width between the items at the desired ratio:

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

  <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-x-4">
      <div class="basis-full min-w-0 lg:basis-0 lg:grow-[7] bg-red-500 h-10">
      </div>
      <div class="basis-full min-w-0 lg:basis-0 lg:grow-[5] bg-blue-500 h-10">
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: The third example you've given here is what I would consider the "correct" answer.
- Removing gutters isn't an option — I should be able to use gutters on my layout.
- Incorporating the margin as a calc is just silly IMHO. It'd be easier/more maintainable to write some custom CSS.
It's a shame really. There's a lot to like about tailwind, but the lack of a robust grid system just makes it nigh-on impossible for me to warrant using it going forward.